Cloud function V2 deployment
Billing error while deploying cloud functions onDocumentCreated trigger with v2 api for cloud functions.
I tried to deploy the below function, got this error:"Write access to project 'xxxxx' was denied: please check billing account associated and retry"**. Not sure why it does not let me when I can easily upload V1 functions.
const { onDocumentCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const { getMessaging } = require('firebase-admin/messaging');
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');

initializeApp();


exports.sendNotificationOnSales = onDocumentCreated('sales/{docId}', async (event) => {
  const newData = event.data.data();

  const itemName=newData['Item name'];
  const itemPrice=newData['Price'];

  const message = {
    topic: 'sale',
    notification: {
      title: 'New item for sale has been added',
      body: `${itemName} ${itemPrice}`,
    },
  };

  try {
    await getMessaging().send(message);
    console.log('Notification sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
  }
});




Did you set a minimum instance? If so, even if you are under the free tier, you need to add a valid billing account.The new version, are basically cloud run functions in GCP, when you upgrade you need to have a valid billing account.
Details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/version-comparison
